# Looking for a Perl or sed one-liner to replace a string with contents from another file

Tags: perl, string, file, replace, sed

In an HTML file, let’s call it `index.html`, I want to replace a comment string, say `//gac goes here`, with the contents (multi-line) from a separate file which is called: gac.js. Is there a nice one-liner for that?

I found something as: `sed -e "/$str/r FileB" -e "/$str/d" FileA`, but it is not working as promised.

I do like it as short as possible, as it will be called after an [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) revert (I don't want any of that google.script polluting my development environment).

Comment: is the contents of the file gac.js multi-lined or sinle line?

Comment: gac.js is multi-line (edited)

Comment: That sed command works for me. What goes wrong?

Comment: Not very experienced with sed but i think i did something wrong with the slash forwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work, even though it is nasty:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{open F,"gac.js";@f=<F>}s#//gac goes here#@f#' index.html
```

In the case that `gac.js` is supposed to be dynamic:

```
perl -pe 's#//(\S+) goes here#open+F,"$1.js";join"",<F>#e' index.html
```

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -mFile::Slurp -pe 's/\/\/(\w+) goes here/@{[File::Slurp::read_file("$1.js")]}/;'
```

Obviously requires File::Slurp

Answer (score 1):

Not very nice, but seems to work:

```
cat index.html | perl -pe 'open(GAC, "gac.js");@gac=<GAC>;$data=join("", @gac); s/gac goes here/$data/g'
```

Comment: I think gac is supposed to be dynamic.

Comment: Useless use of cat (http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) and you are reading in `gac.js` every time you read a line from `index.html`

Comment: @Chas Owens, your version is better :). +1 for that

Answer (score 1):

After going through `man sed`, [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) tutorial and some experimenting I came up with:

```
sed -i '\_//gac goes here_ {
    r gac.js
    d 
}' index.html
```

Which does exactly what I want. It's not exactly a oneliner (if i make it one line i get: `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched '{'`) which I don't understand. However expression above fits nicely in my update script.

Lessons learned: sed is very powerfull, -i behaves different on mac os x / linux, /string/ can easily be replaced with \[other delimiter]string[other delimiter].

Comment: The reason the '{' is unmatched is that sed takes everything from the r to the newline as the filename, so the closing brace is interpreted as part of the filename.